# solaris sftp: remove remote folder

Tags: linux, solaris, sftp

Does anybody know how to remove remote directory via sftp?
sftp doesn't support "rm -r" only "rm", so the only way I see is to save remote folder tree in a file with "rm" prefix and then execute `sftp -b file`
And as sftp doesn't support "ls -lR" either I have to use "ls -l" in the loop to create such a file.

Is there an easier way? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try, lftp. If you want to remove the directory `foo` and all its subfolders `rm -r foo` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Would `del -s` do what you're looking to do?

Answer (score 1):

`rm -r` seems to work fine for recursively removing a remote directory with files in it.

```
$ sftp --version
sftp: SSH Tectia Client 6.0.2 on sparc-sun-solaris2.8
Build: 84
Product: SSH Tectia Client
License type: commercial
SFT API: 2.0.3 (build 6.0.2.84)
```

Comment: doesn't work on SunOS ucmpr 5.10 Generic_144488-06 sun4us sparc FJSV,GPUZC-M

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_sftp.htm shows that you can use `rmdir`

see the answer at https://superuser.com/questions/595401/why-is-sftp-rmdir-not-working

direct quote from [Chris](https://superuser.com/users/8587/chris):

```
In my experience, rmdir prefers to work on an empty directory. If you're trying to delete the directory foo, I would do:

$rm foo/*
$rmdir foo
```

Comment: Note however that your updated answer does not work if you have files/directories in the directories in the `foo` directory. (I.e., it's not a general solution.)